# javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException

Tags: java, jmx, mbeans

I am relatively new to Managed Beans in java and i am trying to figure out why i am getting an exception.After running Main.java,i get the exception pasted at the bottom.I tried to view it on jconsole but it doesnt seem to be appearing.What iam i missing?

Hello.java

```
package com.mbeans;

public class Hello implements HelloMBean {

private final String name = "Reginald"; 
private int cacheSize = DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE; 
private static final int 
DEFAULT_CACHE_SIZE = 200; 

public void sayHello() { 
System.out.println("hello, world"); 
} 

public int add(int x, int y) { 
return x + y; 
} 

public String getName() { 
return this.name; 
}  

public int getCacheSize() { 
return this.cacheSize; 
} 

public synchronized void setCacheSize(int size) {

this.cacheSize = size; 
System.out.println("Cache size now " + this.cacheSize); 
} 

}
```

HelloMBean.java

```
package com.mbeans;

public interface HelloMBean { 

public void sayHello(); 
public int add(int x, int y); 

public String getName(); 

public int getCacheSize(); 
public void setCacheSize(int size); 
}
```

Main.java

```
package com.mbeans;

import java.lang.management.*; 
import javax.management.*; 

public class Main { 

public static void main(String[] args) 
throws Exception { 


Worker worker = new Worker();

} 
}
```

Worker.java

```
package com.mbeans;

import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.util.logging.Level;

import javax.management.MBeanServer;
import javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler;
import javax.management.MalformedObjectNameException;
import javax.management.ObjectName;


public class Worker {


MBeanServer mbs; 
HelloMBean mbean;

public Worker()
{

this.mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
ObjectName name = null;
try
{
name = new ObjectName("com.mbeans:type=HelloMBean");
}
catch (MalformedObjectNameException ex)
{
ex.printStackTrace();
}

try
{

this.mbean = ((HelloMBean)MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(this.mbs, name, HelloMBean.class, false));


}
catch(Exception e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}


System.out.println("online : " +this.mbean.add(3, 4));


}

}
```

This is the exception i am getting

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy2.add(Unknown Source)
at com.mbeans.Worker.<init>(Worker.java:45)
at com.mbeans.Main.main(Main.java:12)
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: com.mbeans:type=HelloMBean
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.getMBean(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(Unknown Source)
... 3 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not [registered](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/MBeanServer.html#registerMBean(java.lang.Object,%20javax.management.ObjectName)) your MBean. It's probably not a best practice to do so, but you could add the registration to your **Worker** constructor just to get things going. Add this line to your constructor after the creation of the ObjectName:

```
this.mbs.registerMBean(this, name);
```

(You will need to add catches for a handful of new exceptions)

_------

Sorry. Did not read carefully enough. You need to register an instance of Hello.

Comment: From what i am told, Since we want to run the methods directly, this line handles that       this.mbean = ((HelloMBean)MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(this.mbs, name, HelloMBean.class, false));

Comment: MBean class com.mbeans.Worker does not implement DynamicMBean, and neither follows the Standard MBean conventions (javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: Class com.mbeans.Worker is not a JMX compliant Standard MBean) nor the MXBean conventions (javax.management.NotCompliantMBeanException: com.mbeans.Worker: Class com.mbeans.Worker is not a JMX compliant MXBean)

Comment: Updated. The mbean is Hello and that needs to be registered, not worker. The proxy invoker still requires a registered mbean, it simply converts method invocations into raw JMX calls.

Comment: I added these 2 lines after creating the object name                             Hello mbean = new Hello();                               this.mbs.registerMBean(mbean, name);